# getting no response from php google geocode rest api request

Tags: php, curl, google-api, geocode

I'm getting no response and no errors from this php code. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong, please? It seems straightforward:

php:

```
$details_url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=436+Grant+Street+Pittsburgh&sensor=false&key=mykey";
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
   $response = curl_exec($ch);
   print_r($response);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never bothered to tell curl about your url. You should have

```
$ch = curl_init($details_url);
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

or

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $details_url);
```

And note that print_r is not a good debug tool. You probably got a boolean false from curl_exec, which print_r won't display at all:

```
php > $x = false;
php > print_r($x);
php > var_dump($x);
bool(false)
```

A better option would be

```
$response = curl_exec($ch);
if ($response === false) {
    die(curl_error($ch));
}
```